# how does spark push down filter work with cassandra table non partition keys?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a table in cassandra where date is not part of partition key but it is part of clustering key. While reading the table in spark I am applying date filter and it is being pushed down. I want to understand how push down works because through cql we cannot query directly on clustering key. Is the data being filtered somewhere?

Implementation in Java:

```
transactions.filter(transactions.col("timestamp").gt(timestamp))  //column timestamp is of type timestamp
```

and the physical plan coming out as

`== Physical Plan ==
*Project [customer_user_id#67 AS customerUserId#111, cast(timestamp#66 as date) AS date#112, city#70]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(timestamp#66) && isnotnull(city#70))
   +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@571db8b4 [customer_user_id#67,timestamp#66,city#70] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(timestamp), *GreaterThan(timestamp,2018-08-13 00:00:00.0), IsNotNull(city)], ReadSchema: struct<customerUserId:int,date:date,city:string>`

Also for timestamp part this worked fine but if column is of type `date` then if was not pushing the filter even if date was part of partition key.  I had to write it as `transactions.filter("date >= cast('" + timestamp + "'as date)")` to make it work. (column date is of type date)

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have a condition on partition key, Spark Cassandra connector uses token ranges to perform effective scanning in parallel. So if you have condition on some clustering column `clasCol` (greater as in your example), connector will generate following query (pseudo-code, not real code - you can find real CQL queries if you enable debug logging):

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM ks.table WHERE
  token(pk) > :startRange AND token(pk) <= :endRange
  AND clasCol > :your-value ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Then Cassandra will perform effective range scans for multiple partitions on the same node. You can look for [code here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/CassandraTableScanRDD.scala#L287) if you want more details.

Regarding `date` - it's requires looking more into the code, but maybe it's just some type conversion missing, or something like - you can check what queries were generated for both cases.

Comment: It means, Cassandra connector is by itself adding ALLOW FILTERING for the queries with filter on Clustering key. Please correct me if I am wrong?